# EU power adapter for UK laptop

Tags: power-supply, power, conversion

My laptop uses a standard clover-leaf 240v 3A UK power lead. I bought a "laptop power lead" for use in Europe. However, it seems to be rated for 16A, is this normal or is it overkill for use with my laptop?

Comment: That's the plug's rating. I expect the cable is probably rather thin, and rated for something like 4A.

Comment: Can you provide picture(s) and/or product numbers? For a laptop power adapter, you probably will be fine with a (trustworthy) cable that fits both required AC power connections.

Answer (score 1):

Probably overkill, but that is irrelevant. The rating of the cable need only be the same or higher than the rating of the original. It may be worth changing the fuse in the plug (if it has one) to a 3A fuse to match the original cable, but the fuses in the plugs are typically there to protect the cable from melting, not the device connected to it, so changing it is not essential.

The leads are purely passive - that is to say they contain no active parts. In fact it is simply 3 copper cables and some insulation. If the cable has a higher rating, it simply means that the copper cables are thicker, not that it will deliver more current.

The only disadvantage of using the higher rated cable is that it will be physically larger - less flexible, harder to pack up into a neat space for travelling.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal. Since the power lead's rating is more than what is necessary, nothing to worry about. It actually makes things a little more safer because it can withstand higher currents in case of fluctuations(although it is unlikely to ever happen in Europe). It's just that the new power lead may be bulkier compared to your original one. Your laptop's power adapter would consume only the necessary power(that is 240v 3A) even though the lead is capable of withstanding higher currents. Don't worry!